# Remove multiple keys from dictionary from txt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

So I have a txt file with this reddit comments:

[image]

There's a lot of information on each line of the dict, and I only want 2 elements from there, which is **author** and **body**. I'm trying to iterate over each line of the file, to remove the unnecessary information and keep only those two. I searched a lot and I didn't found any thing that help me.

The output should be a new filename.txt with only author and body in the dict for each line.

I just realize that it is in json format. So I tried this:

The problem is, now when I remove the unnecessary elements, it also removes it's value.

```
    listcomments = []
    for line in open ('RC_2009-01.json', 'r'):

        listcomments.append(json.loads(line))

        #res = dict([(key, val) for key, val in comments.items() if key not in rem_list]) 
        #print(res)

    for line in listcomments:

        rem_list = ['subreddit_id', 'name', 'author_flair_text', 'link_id', 'score_hidden', 'retrieved_on', 'controversiality',
                    'parent_id', 'subreddit', 'author_flair_css_class', 'created_utc', 'gilded', 'archived', 'distinguished',
                    'id', 'edited', 'score', 'downs', 'ups']     

        list1 = [ele for ele in line if ele not in rem_list]

        out_file = open("teste2.json", "w") 
        json.dump(list1, out_file, indent = 4)
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then provide a sample dict and/or the format of the CSV

Comment: The sample is the picture. File is too big so I just showed the first two lines of it. Each line has all of that informations and I want to remove all of it except 'author' and 'body' elements.

Comment: Iterating over lines won't work here, since the data is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Example in the image file is in json format. You have to parse json and get needed tags from the parser.
forward the following link :

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

You do this.

Say you have a dictionary like this below.

```
a={chr(i):j for i,j in zip(range(65,91),range(1,27))}

'''a={'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9,
'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17, 'R': 18,
 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}'''
```

And you want to extract only `'A'` and `'C'`.

```
wanted_key=['A','C']
res={key:a.get(key) for key in wanted_key}
print(res)
```

---

output

```
{'A': 1, 'C': 3}
```